# A bug in reputation calculation. I don't see reputation change from docs

Tags: bug, documentation, reputation

It seems I found a bug.

On May 19, 2017, I added the example

[Spring JSR 303 Bean Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring/9882/spring-jsr-303-bean-validation/30721/valid-usage-to-validate-nested-pojos#t=201705221325365596204)

And today it is approved. I can see the article (I even tried to see when I am not logged in to be sure the article is visible for everybody) and I can see `created by` me.

But If I open my reputation from profile I don't see `+2` from `doc change`.

Is it bug or I miss some rules?

Comment: Why do you expect reputation from just writing that example? You get rep when that example gets upvotes or if you edited an example. (or do you have a sources what writing the example already provides reputation?)

Comment: @Tom I added one more example to the same topic (May 15) The `Spring JSR 303 Validation - Customize error messages` and I got +2. It is also 0 vote ups. For me it's strange. Two almost the same examples added to the same topic with the same results (0 upvotes) and I got +2 for the first and nothing for the second. It is not question of reputation is a question why the behavior is different. Looks like a bug